# The -Match switch is not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm using quser to get rdp session in disconnected stated

The -match is not working as i expected '$env:USERNAME' is ignore

```
$computers = 'computer1','computer2','computer3','computer4'

foreach ($computer in $computers){

quser /server:$computer | ? { $_ -match “Disc” -and '$env:USERNAME'}|foreach {
$Session = ($_ -split ‘ +’)[2]
$user = ($_ -split ‘ +’)[1]
$idletime= ($_ -split ‘ +’)[4]
logoff /SERVER:$computer $Session 
}}
```

Comment: What did you expect? What happened? What is `-and '$env:USERNAME'` supposed to do (it will always evaluate to `$true` btw)? Did you perhaps mean to do `$_ -match "Disc" -and $_ -match $env:USERNAME`?

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen $_ -match "Disc" -and $_ -match $env:USERNAME worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-and` operator is a boolean logic operator - it evaluates the expressions on either side, coerces them to a `[bool]` (eg. `$true` or `$false`), and then returns `$true` if, and only if *both* expressions evaluated to `$true`.

Coercing a non-empty string (like `'$env:USERNAME'`) to `[bool]` invariably results in `$true`:

```
PS ~> [bool]'$env:USERNAME'
True
```

So the condition you're effectively evaluating is:

```
($_ -match "Disc") -and $true
```

Which is logically the exact same as just doing:

```
$_ -match "Disc"
```

on its own.

If you want to perform 2 `-match` comparisons and ensure they're both true, you'll want to change the expression to:

```
... |? { $_ -match "disc" -and $_ -match $env:USERNAME } | ...
```

Notice that I'm not surrounding `$env:USERNAME` in `''` - quoting it in single quotes creates a string with the literal value `$env:USERNAME` (which is not a valid account name in windows)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation